# Function Application Operator ($) in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

Let's say I have this code

```
let identifier = spaces_surrounded (many1Satisfy isLetter)
```

I was wondering if it there was any native F# function that allowed me to refactor it to

```
let identifier = spaces_surrounded $ many1Satisfy isLetter
```

that is, something such as

```
let ($) f1 f2 = f1 (f2)
```

(that is if I am not mistaken, my Haskell skills are not too sharp..).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The standard F# idiom for this is the forward pipe operator `|>` were you would rewrite

```
let identifier = spaces_surrounded (many1Satisfy isLetter)
```

as

```
let identifier = many1Satisfy isLetter |> spaces_surrounded
```

you can also use the backward pipe operator `<|` if you want to maintain the original order, but this tends to be a little less common

```
let identifier = spaces_surrounded <| many1Satisfy isLetter
```

Comment: Hmm so it seems <| is what I was looking for. What is its definition?

Comment: It is `let inline (<|) f x = f x` as seen here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs

Comment: Note that defining your own operators a la Haskell is subject to F# rules of associativity/precedence, e.g. see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597402

Comment: The (<|) operator associates the other way from ($), and the type-checker seems better at inferring what I went when I use (|>), so watch out for both of those.

Comment: @antoine The type inferrence works left to right, so using `|>` will almost always give better type inference results than `<|` which is why `|>` is so common in f# code

Comment: if you work with F# in an productive env. then you will see <| a lot more often (ignore <| ...), (... <| new Bla(...)) - it just saves a lot parentheses - just like $ does in Haskell

Comment: @CKoenig - I tend to use `..|> ignore` the only real exception being the `*printf` functions.  A quick grep of the F# source tree gives `~/FSharp-2.0.0.0/source $ grep -r "|>" * | wc -l :3357                   ~/FSharp-2.0.0.0/source $ grep -r "<|" * | wc -l :83`

Comment: well "ignore <| stuff" reads nicer than the other way round but I guess it's just a preference (and looking at your greps I might be a weirdo ;) ). The only think I don't like is mixing <| and |>.

Comment: man I wish we had this in C#