# F# equivalent to Haskell's $

Tags: f#

What is the F# equivalent to Haskell's $?

The operator that does the parenthesis automagically.

Google didnt help :(

Something that allows me to write

```
printfn "%d" $ Seq.sum nums
```

Instead of this

```
printfn "%d" (Seq.sum nums)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the forward/backward pipe operator. Backward pipe operator is used to maintain the orginal  order and forward must me turned over. [Function Application Operator ($) in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183903/function-application-operator-in-f)

Backward pipe  operator

```
printfn "%d" <| Seq.sum nums
```

Forward pipe operator

```
Seq.sum nums |> printfn "%d"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never Haskell, but perhaps you're looking for the reverse pipeline operator (`<|`)?

```
printfn "%d" <| Seq.sum nums
```