# Anything *else* similar to Haskell's $ in F# other than <|?

Tags: f#

I know there's the back-pipe `(<|)` operator, referenced in several other SO answers.  But that doesn't work well when combined with forward pipes `(|>)`, which is common in chaining.  However I'm looking for related options.  Basically is there any built-in version of the below function definition?  Or is this a bad/dangerous practice?

```
let inline (^%) f = f

let stuff = 
  [1;2;3]
  |> Seq.filter ^% (>) 2
  |> Seq.map ^% fun x -> x.ToString()


// compare to this, which doesn't compile (and would be hard to follow even if it did)
let stuff = 
  [1;2;3]
  |> Seq.filter <| (>) 2
  |> Seq.map <| fun x -> x.ToString()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function Application Operator ($) in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183903/function-application-operator-in-f)

Comment: Nope. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7183903/3909293

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about Haskell to answer, but take a look at [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl) and search answers by [Gustavo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/446822/gustavo?tab=answers)

Comment: @GuyCoder what has this to do with Haskell or the *simulated* type-classes?

Comment: btw: I guess you want something similar to `$` in Haskell but for an F#er both your proposals seems to be *less* readable than simply using `(..)` (as in `Seq.filter ((>) 2)` - also the last one is simply `Seq.map string` ;)

Comment: @Carsten okay, that's essentially the clarification I was looking for.

Comment: @Carsten I was just giving the OP another place to look, I didn't claim it was an answer but I do know that when I seek info that has touch points between Haskell and F# I often run across Gustavo's items.

Comment: @carsten btw never knew about `string`. Even though completely unrelated, wish I asked this question two years ago.

Comment: it's just one of those *cast* functions like `int`, `double`, ... ;) - but yeah you would look for something like`toString` I guess ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some Haskell features, like optional *infixing* using backticks, and *sections*, which aren't available in F#. That makes certain constructs a bit more verbose.

Usually, I'd simply write a pipe of functions as the above like this:

```
let stuff = 
  [1;2;3]
  |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x < 2)
  |> Seq.map string
```

This is, in my opinion, much more readable. For example, using `Seq.filter ^% (>) 2`, I'd intuitively *read* that as meaning 'all values greater than 2', but that's not what it does:

```
> let inline (^%) f = f;;

val inline ( ^% ) : f:'a -> 'a

> let stuff = 
  [1;2;3]
  |> Seq.filter ^% (>) 2
  |> Seq.map ^% fun x -> x.ToString()
  |> Seq.toList;;

val stuff : string list = ["1"]
```

If you leave the reader of the code in doubt of what the code does, you've just made everyone less productive. Using `Seq.filter (fun x -> x < 2)` may look more verbose, but is unambiguous to the reader.

Comment: Ironically I'd originally written it as `fun x -> x < 2` when typing out the example and then thought "nah, someone is going to point out how to shorten it".

Comment: Any thoughts on `^%` vs `<|` with regard to http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/03/01/ad-hoc-arbitraries-now-with-pipes/?  I guess they do the same thing in that case so may as well stick with the built-in op.  Though `^%` would help if it was in a `|>` chain.

Comment: i.e. you could do `Gen.elements [4..8]
    |> Arb.fromGen
    |> Prop.forAll ^% fun neighborCount -> ...`

Comment: @DaxFohl That does look enticing :) Most F#ers (me included), however, are quite conservative when it comes to introducing new operators. Readers of code will need to look it up in order to understand what a new operator does, so the benefit of the operator should be substantially greater than the cost of understanding it.